# Erlang - Comparing between ETS tables

Tags: erlang, elixir, erlang-otp, ets

We would like to know how to find mutual elements between two ets tables efficiently, we tried ETS and QLC modules but couldn't find out how to do it,
we are using ets on [bag] option which means that we have several values for the same key.

We are looking for the fastest  and most efficient solution.

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to answer your question since we know nothing about the table size, the structure of their content, the execution context (parallelism?, frequency...)

Did you test the basic solution with lists:filter/2 ?

```
1> ets:new(t,[bag,named_table]).
t
2> ets:new(s,[bag,named_table]).
s
3> ets:insert(t,[{1,a},{1,b},{2,c}]).
true
4> ets:insert(s,[{3,a},{1,b},{2,d}]).
true
5> lists:filter(fun(X) -> lists:member(X,ets:tab2list(s)) end, ets:tab2list(t)).
[{1,b}]
6>
```

if (what I guess) your table are big and/or their content complex, you could create on purpose a new ets set table which key is the full record of your tables, and then filter the record of your second table using the function ets:insert_new/2 as predicate, the overhead of creation may be worth compare to the search of elements:

```
6> ets:new(r,[set,named_table]).                                                
r
7> lists:foreach(fun(X) -> ets:insert(r,{X}) end,ets:tab2list(s)).
ok
8> ets:tab2list(r).
[{{3,a}},{{2,d}},{{1,b}}]
9> lists:filter(fun(Y) -> ets:insert_new(r,{Y}) == false end,ets:tab2list(t)).
[{1,b}]
10>
```

I have used ets:tab2list/1 in this example to make the demo easily in the shell, but any method to traverse the ets table could be used.

Answer (score 1):

You could iterate one table and for each element check whether it is in the second table. Using `ets:select` you could reduce the data being copied.

For example, let's say we construct a following table:

```
1> Tab = ets:new(foo, [bag]).
2> [ets:insert(Tab, {X, Y}) || X <- lists:seq(1,10), Y <- lists:seq(1, 10)].
```

To check whether a pair `{3, 4}` is in the table, you can do:

```
3> ets:select(Tab, [{{3, 4}, [], [true]}]).
[true]
```

If the pair is not in the table, you'll get an empty list:

```
4> ets:select(Tab, [{{3, 11}, [], [true]}]).
[]
```

I'm not 100% sure about performance, but I think, since we're matching the key, that the lookup wold be O(M), where M is the average number of items under the same key.

The final piece is to fetch everything from another table and invoke `ets:select` iteratively. Since you need to fetch all the data from the first table, `ets:tab2list` could be fine, with a caveat that it will cause all the data to be copied. Here's a quick example:

```
5> Tab2 = ets:new(bar, [bag]),
[ets:insert(Tab2, {X, Y}) || X <- lists:seq(7,12), Y <- lists:seq(7, 12)].

% iterate Tab2, return only tuples which exist in Tab
6> [Element || Element <- ets:tab2list(Tab2), ets:select(Tab, [{Element, [], [true]}]) =:= [true]].
```

If both tables are very large, you might want to consider iterating manually with `ets:first`, `ets:next`, and `ets:lookup`, to avoid copying all the data at once.

Of course, it's best to measure and verify which approach works best for your case.